# Проблема с сериализацией function_wrapper

Tags: c++, функции, boost, сериализация

Есть такой код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
using namespace std;

struct impl_base {
        virtual void call() = 0;
        virtual ~impl_base() {}
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version){}
    };
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(impl_base)

    template<typename F>
    struct impl_type : impl_base {
        F f;
        impl_type(F&& f_) : f{std::move(f_)} {}
        void call() { f(); }
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & boost::serialization::base_object<impl_base>(*this) & f;
        }
    };

class function_wrapper {
    std::unique_ptr<impl_base> impl;
public:
    template<typename F>
    function_wrapper(F&& f) : impl(new impl_type<F>(std::move(f))) {}
    void operator()() { impl->call(); }
    function_wrapper() = default;
    function_wrapper(function_wrapper&& other) : impl(std::move(other.impl)) {}
    function_wrapper& operator=(function_wrapper&& other)
    {
        impl = std::move(other.impl);
        return *this;
    }
    function_wrapper(const function_wrapper&) = delete;
    function_wrapper(function_wrapper&) = delete;
    function_wrapper& operator=(const function_wrapper&) = delete;
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) { 
        ar & impl; 
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(function_wrapper)

void hel() { cout << "WTF" << endl;}

void serialize_task()
{
    function_wrapper task(std::bind(&hel));
    task();
    std::ofstream ofs("task.dat");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oar(ofs);
    oar << task;
    ofs.close();

    // Загрузка объекта из файла
    std::ifstream ifs("task.dat");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive iar(ifs);
    function_wrapper loaded_task;
    iar >> loaded_task;
    ifs.close();

    // Проверка результатов сериализации
    loaded_task();
}

int main() {
    serialize_task();
    return 0;
}
```

Есть базовый класс `impl_base`, для которого применяю `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(impl_base)`, как показано в офиц.документации [serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers).
И дальше я пытаюсь тестить при помощи`void serialize_task()`. (`bind` нужен, он на своем месте).

Вопрос в целом - что же надо зарегистрировать, чтобы ошибка

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported`
```

перестала высовываться???
P.S. `Boost` последней версии, собираю при помощи `g++ -o a a.cpp -lboost_serialization`.

---

Как подсказал @user7860670 - у меня все-таки нет регистрации `impl_type`. Тогда я вынес его и `impl_base` из `function_wrapper` и  добавил к коду регистрацию через экспорт `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(impl_type<function<void()>>)` для объекта типа  `function<void()>`, так как у меня в примере должна вызваться функция `void hell(){..}`:

```
struct impl_base {
        virtual void call() = 0;
        virtual ~impl_base() {}
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version){}
    };
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(impl_base)

    template<typename F>
    struct impl_type : impl_base {
        F f;
        impl_type(F&& f_) : f{std::move(f_)} {}
        void call() { f(); }
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & boost::serialization::base_object<impl_base>(*this) & f;
        }
    };
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(impl_type<function<void()>>)

class function_wrapper {....
```

Но это не помогло, так как начала появляться другая ошибка:

```
error: ‘class std::function<void()>’ has no member named ‘serialize’
  116 |         t.serialize(ar, file_version);
```

Что скорее всего свидетельствует о том, что объект  ‘class std::function<void()>’ нельзя сериализовать.

Мой вопрос - это так или нет? Если мои мысли верны, то вопрос можно закрыть, если нет, то прошу совета, что исправить в коде.

Comment: `В классе impl_type делаю регистрацию` - ¿Где именно? Случаем не в `impl_type::serialize`? Так эта функция в коде же не используется.

Comment: @user7860670, 
```boost::serialization::void_cast_register<impl_type<F>, impl_base>(
                static_cast<impl_type<F> *>(NULL),
                static_cast<impl_base *>(NULL)
            );
``` 
вот здесь по моему мнению. Была попытка вынести `impl_base` и `impl_type` из `function_wrapper` и добавить для конкретного случая `F` (в моем варианте `void hell()` следующие:
`BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(impl_type<function<void()>>)`, но это тоже не работает для меня

Comment: Еще раз: Вы осознаете, что `impl_type::serialize`, где это все написано, в коде не используется? Все действия по регистрации должны быть завершены до создания классов и попыток сериализации.

Comment: @user7860670, да, вы правы. Поэтому и нет "зарегистрированных" объектов, кроме `function_wrapper`. но у меня были попытки создать `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(impl_type<function<void()>>)`, что тоже вышли не успешно. Натыкался на другие вопросы, где было сказано, что сериализация функции так таковой не возможна. Видимо поэтому возникает ошибка при действии  `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(impl_type<function<void()>>)`. Как Вы считаете?

Comment: Если `возникает ошибка при действии BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(impl_type<function<void()>>)`, то это необходимо указывать в вопросе, приводя как код, так и содержание ошибки. Телепатов нет.

Comment: @user7860670, вопрос исправлен.

Comment: 1 там пропущена регистрация `impl_base`. 2 при инстанцировании `impl_type<function<void()>>` будет компилироваться кусок `ar & boost::serialization::base_object<impl_base>(*this) & f;` где `f` - `function<void()>`. Не удивительно, что вылезает такая ошибка. И непонятно, чего вы вообще ожидаете от сериализации такого объекта. 3 Далее по коду у вас инстанцируется другой класс `impl_type<decltype(std::bind(&hel))>`, но в нем `f` тоже будет чем-то явно без поддержки сериализации.

Comment: 4 у класса `impl_type` еще же нет конструктора по-умолначию, поэтому придется заморочиться с пробросом аргументов конструктора

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user7860670 дал ответ на мой вопрос.
Ошибка была в том, что не было конструктора по умолчанию для `impl_type`. Плюс нет сериализации для типа `function`, ее нужно самостоятельно обработать ручками - сохранить "имя вызываемой функции" и для нее аргументы. Потом при десериализации "узнав имя функции" воссоздать ее снова, закинув в нее аргументы.